# Problems while trying to use components from another module in intellij idea AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, intellij-idea

i'am trying to use components from another module, but is not working.
Look what i have:
I have my project, its an app to convert files, and its working everything is ok. Now i want to change the interface... for that i cloned a github repository  thats is a project with the components that i want to use, and imported it as a module. (should i import as a module or as a project?)
Everything great till now, but when i try to use the components from the module i cant find the classes or even the module...

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add your imported sources as a new module (let's call it `B`), then you should add a dependency from your original module `A` to your module `B` in order to use its code.

See [this page](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-module-dependencies-and-libraries.html) on how to configure module dependencies.

Comment: something like that! but i just imported the other project as a module, and then in my project's build configuration, in the dependencies aba, add the module as a raw library. 


Now its working perfectly!